# Removing optional paremeters from Texstudio autocomplete

Tags: texstudio, auto-completion

When I use `\cite` command in TexStudio, it's auto completion mechanism suggests the full command as `\cite[add.tex]{key.list}`. When I press enter cursor moves to the location between square brackets. But I hardly (almost never) use optional parameters(`[add.text]`). I have to delete square brackets every time I use `\cite` command which, is very annoying.

Is there a way to edit auto-complete feature in Texstudio so, it only suggests me `\cite{key.list}`?

Comment: Do you still have this problem? `\cite` for me has 2 autocomplete suggestions now, `\cite{bibid}` and `\cite[add.text]{keylist}`, so you can just use the first variant.